# Sendkeys does not preserve formatting (double space)

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I use a userform with a listbox to help filter a online staff list.

The VBA code first present what names it want to filter out and I click a button, the code waits five seconds for me to click on the webpage filter search box.
Then the code loops the names and uses sendkeys to filter out the names I need.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    For i = 0 To lbnorm.ListCount - 1
        Debug.Print lbnorm.List(i, 1)            ' Foo  Bar
        Application.SendKeys (lbnorm.List(i, 1)) ' Foo Bar
        Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}")
        Sleep 200
    Next i
    SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
End Sub
```

The code works fine, except on one person.
Lets call this person Foo Bar. The problem is that the person who wrote Foo's name in the webpage accidentally added another space `Foo  Bar`.

Using the code above the immediate window show `Foo  Bar` but when I sendkeys to notepad it writes `Foo Bar`.
What can I do to get Foo Bar to filtered using sendkeys?

EDIT:
I just tried this code and by some reason this works fine.

```
Sub t()
    b = "aaa  aaa   bbbb"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Debug.Print b
    Application.SendKeys (b)

End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for... do you want to trim the extra space out of `Foo  Bar`? Also, I'd recommend using the browsers API rather than `sendkeys` to input data.

Comment: No, I want to keep the extra space so that Foo Bar can be found in the search bar

Comment: Sendkeys is almost always the worst possible solution for a problem. Prediction: you fix this bug, and another bug pops up a few weeks later (if you stick with send keys). You are essentially pushing buttons in a pitch-black room, hoping that the button you are pushing is the right button, and that you are pushing it at the right time.

Comment: @JohnColeman I know. But that is the only solution since there is no API on the webpage we can use.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)

Comment: The relevant API isn't for the web page per se -- it is for the browser. VBA can interact with the DOM that the browser constructs for a page.

Comment: The webpage does not support IE as far as I know ( I can't get it to run there). The authentication is done through our company portal. Once on the webpage all fields are created and update using JQuery/Ajax or something dynamic. I'm quite sure that will be way to much work for the few bugs that may appear.

Comment: Looks like you found a workaround then `b = aaa  aaa   bbbb`